# Mapping explosion in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few questions related to a number of fields present in mapping and addition of new fields dynamically.
What can be the causes of mapping explosions?
Is it the high number of fields(in my case more than 1000 fields) present in the mapping file or a huge number of documents present?
Are there any other reasons for mapping explosion?

Comment: The main problem is the high number of fields, because doc keys are stored in memory. 
You have it documented here : https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion

Comment: Thanks @jordivador